# How To Print My Page With css & bootstrap styles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to print my website with my CSS and boostrap styles. I'm printing with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> or with a `window.print()` function; I tried including the CSS references in my print function, `media="print"`, and other things but I can't print the page with CSS style and the boostrap styles only appear the div, control and buttons borders without color.

**Example of my css**

```
    body{
    background-color:gainsboro;
    }

    .wrapper {    
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .form-signin {
    max-width: 420px;
    padding: 30px 38px 66px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 3px dotted rgba(0,0,0,0.1);  
    }

    .form-signin-heading {
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

   .form-control {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    }
```

[image: Print preview vs original page]

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this last week unfortunately I did not go fully into making Bootstrap styles printable how ever. in your CSS add

```
@media print {
  p.class-name {
  color: red !important;
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 

  }
}
```

inside @media print you set out how your element should react to print

for instance

```
#breadcrumbs {
  display: none;
}
```

will prevent my element with ID breadcrumbs from showing on the print page.